# Gap Polyfill for Styled Components and Gatsby / Safari suport

Tags: css, safari, gatsby, styled-components

I'm building website with Gatsby + Styled Components and I would love to use css gap property. unfortunately Safari does not support this property so my layouts end up broken. I could rewrite my css with margins etc, but it doesn't seem right.

Is there any way to add polyfill for gap property with Gatsby and Styled Components?

**What I want to achive**

- I would like to use css gap property with suport for Safari

**My issue**

- I couldn't find any polyfill that would work with Gatsby and Styled Components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not "native" way to achieve it, since it's a property that is not standardized (yet) in Safari, as you can see in [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/?search=gap).

Regarding the polyfill, maybe this package helps you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/flex-gap-polyfill

For an input like:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    gap: 40px;
}
```

It will output:

```
.container > * {
    --fgp-gap-parent: 40px !important;
    --fgp-gap-item: 40px !important;
    --fgp-gap: var(--fgp-gap-item) !important;
    margin-top: var(--fgp-gap);
    margin-right: var(--fgp-gap);
}

.container {
    --fgp-gap-container: calc(var(--fgp-gap-parent, 0px) - 40px) !important;
    --fgp-gap: var(--fgp-gap-container);
    margin-top: var(--fgp-gap);
    margin-right: var(--fgp-gap);
}
```

I think you can get exactly the same effect [Simulating the CSS Gap](https://coryrylan.com/blog/css-gap-space-with-flexbox), even with margins, with:

```
.emulated-flex-gap {
  --gap: 12px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: calc(-1 * var(--gap)) 0 0 calc(-1 * var(--gap));
  width: calc(100% + var(--gap));
}

.emulated-flex-gap > * {
  margin: var(--gap) 0 0 var(--gap);
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer. I know that there is no native suport on Safari and i could actually achieve the same effect with margins, I just thought that there probably is a better solution to this issue.

Regarding polyfill that You have kindly linked - I'm afraid that its not compatible with styled components ( or I don't know how to use it properly ) 

I'll have a look at the article, thanks!

Comment: You can use `import FlexGapPolyfill from 'flex-gap-polyfill'` and treat that as your styled one if you want to use that polyfill. If finally the issue has been solved please consider accepting/upvoting the answer to close the issue